# Google tag manager in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-tag-manager

Good day!

I have trouble figuring out how to setup flutter with google tag manager. I have found [this package](http://logohttpswwwgstaticcomimagesbrandingproduct1xgoogleg_16dppng-tag-manager-api---tagmanager-v1) that includes tag manager api. However I don't know how to configure it properly. (On the web I just had to copy paste a snippet into index.html and it worked)

Comment: Did you figure it out ?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/google_tag_manager

Comment: how to use it on flutter web.

Answer (score 0):

As of this moment, there is an available package for [google_tag_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/google_tag_manager) that could be use for the web.  Aside from the package itself, you can also explore this blog about "[Adding Tag Manager to Flutter app](https://akhileshgahlot.medium.com/adding-tag-manager-to-flutter-app-ce528ec7852)".